# How do you install TWRP after rooting?

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp

I have a 2012 Nexus 7 running 5.1.1 and I was wondering how you install TWRP after rooting? I rooted my device using v2.1.0 of the Nexus Root Toolkit with the "custom recovery" box checked and it said it would flash TWRP. My bootloader is unlocked.

I am new at rooting and maybe I don't know how to get to TWRP. You shut down the device, you hold <kbd>Power</kbd>+<kbd>Volume Down</kbd> for 5 seconds or so and you enter a screen that says start next to an Android guy.  I used the volume keys to scroll to Recovery and pressed <kbd>Power</kbd> for Enter. Everything after that was just how it was before the root. I want install CM 12.1 and I want to be sure I have TWRP flashed already so I don't to flash again.

Comment: Cyanogenmod has made a guide how to install their ROM. It also includes unlocking and installing a custom recovery. https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_grouper

Comment: Follow the official instructions: https://twrp.me/devices/asusnexus72012wifi.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To easily flash TWRP while already rooted, you can install [TWRP Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jmz.soft.twrpmanager).  After installation: Open it and select your device, select the version of the recovery that you want to use, hit Install Recovery and let the app download and install it.  The app will automatically prompt you to reboot into the recovery.

---

If you want to ensure that's it's writing to the correct recovery partition, run this command in a root shell/terminal before you do the above:

```
ls -a -l /dev/block/platform/*/by-name
```

It should output a line that looks like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Dec 16 16:18 recovery -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p25
```

Ensure that TWRP Manager asks to write to that latter part (`/dev/block/mmcblk0p25` or whatever the output is on your device.)

---

Another option for rebooting into recovery is to connect your device to a PC and run `adb reboot recovery`.  ADB is part of the Android SDK Tools, which you can get as part of the Android Studio install or stand-alone [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other).

Comment: +1, but other apps like Flashify would also work, maybe you could mention them too (TWRP Manager supports far less devices than Flashify does, and that might help somebody else who comes across this and their TWRP is an unofficial version)

Comment: Okay. Good News. It didn't ever boot up into stock Android, but I did have CM 12.1 and GApps already on my device, so I flashed those and it booted into CyanogenMod perfectly. It did get rid of SuperSU, so it says I am not rooted. If I download SuperSU from the Play Store, it should fix it right?

Comment: @redjack CM has a specific setting for controlling root access that you can use, see [here](http://www.androidexplained.com/cyanogenmod-enable-root/).  If you want SuperSU instead, you'll have to flash the package from [here](https://download.chainfire.eu/supersu-stable).

Comment: Can I download SuperSU from the Play Store instead of flashing it?

Comment: @redjack The SuperSU flash package contains both the app and its version of `su`.  Without the latter, the former is mostly useless.  CM already includes a Privacy Guard feature which essentially does the same thing, so it's best not to mix and match them.  So if you want to avoid more flashing, I would just enable CM's root setting and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

The most common method to flash TWRP (or other recovery) on a Nexus device is to do it manually with `fastboot` which is part of the part of [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) or can be obtained in a compact form with the [Minimal ADB and Fastboot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790) tool (assuming Windows OS). Install one of those on your computer and then download the appropriate TWRP for your device, which for the Nexus 7 can be obtained from the official source [here](https://dl.twrp.me/grouper/) with the newest version at the top of the list, and place the img file in the same directory as adb/fastboot. Then reboot you phone into fastboot mode and issue the command `fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.0.0-0-grouper.img` (the current release of this answer) and once it completes, reboot with `fastboot reboot`.

Official instructions and more detail are available from twrp.me, the official site for TWRP recovery, on their [Asus Nexus 7 2012 WiFi device page](https://twrp.me/devices/asusnexus72012wifi.html).

This is assuming you have an Asus Nexus 7 2012 WiFi (grouper) model the answer should be more than sufficient, if you have the 3G model the answer is mostly the same, but substitute the appropriate TWRP file and flash command for your Asus Nexus 7 2012 3G (talapia) from [here](https://twrp.me/devices/asusnexus720123g.html). Be aware that the recoveries for these two devices do differ, so if you use the incorrect file there is potential to have "problems"

Comment: Thanks for the help! I already flashed it using the TWRP Manager in the previous answer. But again, thanks for your interest.

Comment: The good thing about fastboot is that you can try to use the TRWP and see if it works *without flashing*, doing `fastboot boot recovery twrp-3.0.0-0-grouper.img`. That way you keep your recovery intact.